Vue route name is undefined and path is incorrect
I'm trying to have some logic in my root App.vue (as soon as the app loads) that depends on the current route, but I'm finding the route.name to be undefined, and when I tried logging the path it was incorrect.

I found a solution here:
Wrap your code in router.isReady() like this:
router.isReady().then(() => {
  ...
});

